# Shift+s registering as super key in emacs. How to turn off?

Tags: macos, keyboard, emacs

Whenever I am in emacs normal mode (as opposed to evil), shift+s registers as "S-" (the super key). This means I cannot enter capital S which is pretty annoying.

The problem is obviously due to my .emacs, because the problem does not exist when I run it without my emacs file. My .emacs can be seen here: http://textuploader.com/kity

I have read through the file and can't see anything that should be giving me such problems.I have also tried commenting out lots of stuff and reloading emacs wihtout any luck.

Might I have accidentally rebound the Shift+S combination using the customize-menus?

I am also unable to do F1-k RET Shift+s because then my keypress is just interpreted as "Super".

I am on OS X Mavericks using the 24.4 brew version. I am using Karabiner, but the problem persists when I turn it off. Looking at how the keypress is interpreted in Karabiner Eventviewer I see nothing wrong:[image]

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
(define-key yas-minor-mode-map (kbd "SPACE") nil)
```

That should be `(kbd "SPC")` instead.  `(kbd "SPACE")` just evaluates to `"SPACE"`, which `define-key` interprets as the key sequence <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>P</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>.

Besides, the `S-` display does not mean that the `S` key is interpreted as the super key.  It means that `S` is a prefix key, and that Emacs is waiting for more keys.  Try typing `C-x` and waiting for a second, and you'll see the same thing.